# Replacement video editor for VLC

Tags: windows-xp, vlc-media-player

Using VLC's frame-by-frame mode (hotkey "e") to manually generate snapshots works fine for a certain amount of time, and then causes VLC to hang completely.

This is a [known](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=86157)  issue for VLC. Is there another program I can use to take snapshots of individual frames, or should I continue killing vlc.exe every 2 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried media player classic which comes with the [k lite codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)? It's pretty easy to do "step" then "grab" functions with it.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty easy, and it has the advantage of not freezing.